# How can 이상하다 be used with 네요 grammar?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'm a little confused about how 이상하다 can be used with 네요 grammar. For example consider you want to talk about an strange child.

Is "이상한 아이네요!" a correct form?

Is "아이가 이상하네요!" correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add a non-native speaker perspective - feel free to correct me!

> 아이가 이상하네요

Here, we are adding the subject particle (가) to the word child (아이), and then adding the 네요 'surprise' ending onto the descriptive verb 이상하다.

> 이상한 아이네요

Here, there is a 'hidden' copula, '이다'. 아이네요 is basically '아이 이다'  ('it is a child') with the 네요 'surprise' ending added ('아이이네요') and then shortened to '아이네요'.

이상한 is the form of 이상하다 that is most similar to an English adjective, created by using the ending ㄴ.

So they are both correct remarks - one constructed around 이상하다, one constructed around 이다.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. The meaning of the two sentences you mentioned almost exactly corresponds to the sentences below, respectively.

- This is a strange child.
- This child is strange.

Comment: When you use 네요!, the English translation is: "What a strange child!"

Comment: Does 아이네요 have an elided copula? (아이 이네요 → 아이네요) ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the terminology, but I think you're on the right track. When the last letter has an ending consonant (?), it becomes 이네요. (이상한 아이네요! / 이상한 선생님이네요!)

Comment: @topo morto Though 아이이네요 is correct, I tend to feel that this word is a bit awkward to be uttered. 아이네요 may be more natural.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy and StephenCheong thanks - I've tried to expand my thought into an answer - feel free to correct it!

Comment: I feel there is some problem with 아이네요... there is no verb here! How about 아이이네요 ??

Comment: @Hanna I think that's what we're saying (and what I was trying to point out in my answer) - it *is* '아이이네요'? but the '이이' gets condensed down to a single '이' according to the rules of natural pronunciation.

Comment: @topomorto Is there any rule for condensing down? I mean in writing.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be the best person to give an accurate answer. Why don't you ask a new question about what rules are being used in that case? It would be a good question :)

Comment: @topomorto So you mean 이상한 아이네요! is surely grammatically correct?

Comment: @Hanna Everyone here seems to agree it is correct :)

Answer (score 3):

Two sentences are grammatically correct, and may convey the same meaning.

But in my opinion, "아이가 이상하네요" or "아이가 이상해요" sounds more like the speaker is worried about a child's health (or mental).
On the other hand, "이상한 아이네요" sounds like the speaker is annoyed by the bad behavior of the child or simply cannot understand the behavior.

I have no theoretical support for this, but I found it also applies to some other cases. 
"차가 이상하네" -> something is going on with this car!
"이상한 차네" -> what a strange car!

Comment: The case I used the sentence was the second one.

Comment: If 이상한 차네요 is correct, we are adding a noun to 네요. Can this form be used in writing?

Answer (score 1):

The ending '[-네](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=7428000)' means:

> 어미
>
> (‘이다’의 어간, 용언의 어간 또는 어미 ‘-으시-’, ‘-었-’, ‘-겠-’ 뒤에 붙어)
>
> 1. 하게할 자리에 쓰여, 단순한 서술의 뜻을 나타내는 종결 어미.
>
> 자네 차례네. 집이 참 넓네. 나 지금 가네.
>
> 2. 해할 자리나 혼잣말에 쓰여, 지금 깨달은 일을 서술하는 데 쓰이는 종결 어미. 흔히 감탄의 뜻이 드러난다.
>
> 우리 아이 노래도 잘 부르네! 집이 참 깨끗하네. 개나리꽃이 정말 노랗네.

Short summary:

'-네' is a final ending used for two purposes.

1. It is used as a final ending in place of '-다'. For example:

> 집이 참 넓네. The house is very large. = 집이 참 넓다.
>
> 나 지금 가네. I am going now. = 나 지금 간다.

2. It is used when you use 'soliloquy (혼잣말)' and it has a connotation of exclamation. For example:

> 집이 참 깨끗하네. What a clean house it is. (How clean your house is).

Your question:

> Is "이상한 아이네요!" a correct form?

Yes, '-요' is an honorific auxiliary and the sentence sounds more honorific than "이상한 아이네.". As @topomorto answered, it connotes your surprise in an exclamatory sentence. It literally translates to "What a strange kid (s)he is" or "How strange the kid is."

> Is "아이가 이상하네요!" correct?

Yes, again, '-요' is an honorific auxiliary. It is more honorific than "아이가 이상히네." and it literally translates to "The kid is strange." or "What a strange kid (s)he is."

Answer (score 1):

이상하다 바보같다

사람들이하지않는 생각을하거나 사람들이 하지 않는 행동을 하는것

예시

너 왜 아무도안하는짓을해? 바보야?

너 왜 아무도안하는데 너만하고있어? 이상한녀석이네?

해석
생각은 상상의 자유다
사람들이 하지않는 생각을하거나 그런행동을 한다면 다른사람들이 보는 관점에서
같이 어울리기싫고 대화하기 싫고 함께하기 싫은사람이될수있다
하지만 이것은 사람들의 고정관념이다
나는 이렇게말하겠다 그 이상하고 바보같은행동들이
때때로 새로운 지식이되고 발명이되며 아무도 생각하지못한 아이디어가된다
이상한 생각이란 그 한사람의 상상력이며 아이디어다

예시 재해석

너 진짜 독특하구나

너 아무도 하지못한 생각을 해냈구나 대단하다

해석2
아이,청소년,성인, 나이를 불문라고 이상한 행동을 하는데에는 이유가있다
그렇다면 관찰해라 그 말과 행동에는 내가 생각하지 못한 의미가 존재하며
때때로 진짜 이상한사람이아닌 톡특한사람 뛰어난사람 자유로운사람이다

대한민국20대청년